# Whose are the cards played through Mesmerize considered to be?

Tags: vampire-the-masquerade-vendetta

The Malkavian player has two related cards:

**Chaos**

> You may choose to take 1 or more of **your** Deployed cards at this Location back into your hand, including this one. For each card you take back, Steal 1 blood from each Rival.

**Mesmerize**

> Choose a Rival. Play all of the cards remaining in their hand on your Position at this Location, face up.

Can the Malkavian player return cards played through Mesmerize to their hand and steal blood with them through Chaos? Or the **your** modifier on Chaos explicitly means your own clan cards only?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The cards played via Mesmerize are treated as the Malkavian's deployed cards. You can take them into your hand via Chaos.

See the publisher's answer in [this thread on BGG](https://boardgamegeek.com/thread/2561635/mesmerize):

> > Mesmerized card on the table goes back to the original owner's hand at the end of the round. But I don't know what would happen if I try taking that card into my hand by playing Chaos. Is mesmerized card MY card so that I can use Chaos or Mindless Assault etc. on that card?

> Yes indeed, the Mesmerized cards are considered as part of your Clan deck in regard of any effect, but you'll have to give them back at the end of the round of course.